# Is There '?' Control Flow in Python?

Tags: python, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python Ternary Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/python-ternary-operator)

Is there control flow operator similar to '?' of C/C++ in python?

If there is a chunk of code similar to this:

```
return n <= 1 ? n : fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

Will got an error like this:

```
File "fibonacci.py", line 2
    return n <= 1 ? n : fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It may be called that incorrectly;  It takes three operands and so it is ternary in the same way that addition is binary.  It happens that there arent many ternary operators in python or other algol descendands.  This is uniquely identified as in phihag's answer as a "Conditional Expression"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the conditional expression is [available in Python 2.5+](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
return n if n <= 1 else fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
```

Comment: things to note are that the condition is in the middle of the python version of this.  C-like languages have `<cond> ? <yes_expr> : <no_expr>` but python has the more fluent `<yes_expr> if <cond> else <no_expr>`

Answer (score 5):

You can try this short circuit expression `return n > 1 and fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2) or n`. While this is not the ternary statement, it is concise and does the job in this scenario.

Comment: I don't think this works for `n==0`